# Use GNU Parallel when file has a single (long) line

Tags: shell-script, shell, parallelism, gnu-parallel, data

I have a file which is an HTML document, containing a `<table>` I want to extract data from and output into a csv.

This file has `544609657` characters, is about 545 megabytes, all in a single line.

I managed to extract the data into a csv by using `sed` and making many string replacements, but I wanted to speed things up by using GNU parallel. Is this possible, considering it's a single line file?

My attempts below have not increased processing speed nor improved memory usage:

```
parallel -a table.html --pipepart 'sed -e [...etc.]' > table.csv
```

Or

```
cat table.html | parallel --pipe 'sed -e [...etc.]' > table.csv
```

I'm guessing the problem is because the file has a single line. If so, what strategies could I used to process the file more efficiently?

Comment: 545 megabytes for an HTML file is highly unusual. Are you sure it isn't actually XML ? Have you tried an XML parser of some sort ? You may already have one available on your system.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's really an HTML. It's bad practice but it's how the data is. Not sure if an XML parser would help speed up the processing of the file... I guess my question might be badly formulated but what I really wanted to know is how to parallel process a file like this one (when it's in a single line)

Comment: I can't see how that would be the solution. On multiple files perhaps. Even if you could do parallel processing disk access should be the bottleneck. Parsing such a big file is never going to be quick, that's why I would look at a native parser, rather than tools like sed. I think an XML parser could work as long as the file is properly structured. If you have [xmllint](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) you could try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly the correct thoughts.

You just need to learn `--recstart`:

```
parallel --pipepart --recstart '<tr>' -a big --block -10 'sed ...' > table.csv
```

Here we assume each row of your HTML table starts with `<tr>`.

Comment: This is great, thank you! `--recstart` allows specifying the start of records, which is defaulted to newlines. Using `<tr>` makes `parallel` treat every table row as a different record, allowing it to actually process the file in parallel.

Comment: @BernardoLoureiro Almost. `--recend` defaults to `\n`. But when `--recstart` is set `--recend` is set to "".

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your clarification, Ole!