# Use GNU parallel with very long lines

Tags: sed, gnu-parallel, large-files

I have a very large SQL dumpfile (30GB) that I need to edit (do some find/replace) before loading back into the database.

Besides having a large size, the file also contains very long lines. Except for the first 40 and last 12 lines, all other lines have lenghts ~ 1MB. These lines are all INSERTO INTO commands that all look alike:

```
cat bigdumpfile.sql | cut -c-100
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (951068,1407592,0.0267,0.0509,0.121),(285
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (238317,1407664,0.008,0.0063,0.1286),(241
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (938922,1407739,0.0053,0.0024,0.031),(226
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (44678,1407886,0.0028,0.0028,0.0333),(234
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (910412,1407961,0.001,0.0014,0),(911017,1
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (903890,1408050,0.0066,0.01,0.0287),(9095
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (257090,1408136,0.0023,0.0037,0.0196),(56
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (593367,1408237,0.0066,0.0117,0.0286),(95
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (870488,1408339,0.0131,0.009,0.0135),(870
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (282798,1408414,0.0015,0.014,0.014),(2830
...
```

Parallel ends with an error on long lines:

```
parallel -a bigdumpfile.sql -k sed -i.bak 's/table1/newtable/'
parallel: Error: Command line too long (1018952 >= 63543) at input 0: INSERT INTO `table1...
```

Because all lines are similar and I only need the find/replace to happen at the beginning of the line I've follwed the advice [in this similar question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642939/use-gnu-parallel-when-file-has-a-single-long-line) with a nice suggestion to use `--recstart` and `--recend`. However these are not working:

```
parallel -a bigdumpfile.sql -k --recstart 'INSERT' --recend 'VALUES' sed -i.bak 's/table/newtable/'
parallel: Error: Command line too long (1018952 >= 63543) at input 0: INSERT INTO `table1...
```

Tried a number of variations using `--block` but could not get it working. I am a GNU parallel newbie, and doing something wrong or just missing something obvious. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

This is using `GNU parallel 20240122`.

Comment: Your usage of `parallel` makes no sense. Sounds like you want `sed s/table1/newtable/ bigdumpfile.sql | sql some-database`

Comment: Yes thanks! I realized I was invoking parallel wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `--pipe` (or `--pipepart`). If your disks are fast:

```
parallel -a bigdumpfile.sql --pipe-part --block 100M -k -q sed 's/table1/newtable/' | sql ...
```

If they are slow:

```
parallel -j1 -a bigdumpfile.sql --pipe-part --block 100M -k -q sed 's/table1/newtable/' | sql ...
```

Adjust `-j` to find the best for your disks.

If you are really trying to run multiple inserts in parallel:

```
# Create the table
head -n 40 bigdumpfile.sql | sql ...
# do the INSERTs in parallel
do_ins() {
  grep 'INSERT INTO' |
    sed s/table1/newtable/ |
    sql ...
}
export -f do_ins
parallel -a bigdumpfile.sql --pipe-part --block -1 do_ins
```

But as Stéphane Chazelas suggests: It may be faster to just do:

```
sed s/table1/newtable/ bigdumpfile.sql | sql some-database
```

Comment: Thanks Ole for the nice additional example to run multiple inserts in parallel!